Connect two networks over a VPN connection linux
I need to connect two networks over a VPN. On each network I have a linux machine that connects to a VPN server on the Internet.
Client A: 
  local 192.168.5.5
  vpn: 10.0.0.5
Client B:
  local 192.168.10.10
  vpn: 10.0.0.10
VPN server: 
  10.0.0.1

Clients A and B are set up as gateways with IP forwarding enabled.
I want to be able to access their respective local networks while connected to the VPN.
Routes have been added on A, B and the VPN server.
I'm pretty sure I should do some iptables rules, but wanted to ask before making a mess of my iptables.

There are no specific iptables rules for connecting networks. Iptables doesn't do routing – it does filtering, whereas your routing table does routing – so the only iptables rules you may need are filter FORWARD chain rules to allow packets to go through, in case the existing rules don't allow that.

You're right, I was just confused, I did touch networking for over a decade and this was my first time using Wireguard, completely missed that it more like p2p2 than server client setup.

The important bit was that I was using Wireguard, so adding the subnets to allowedIPs in the WG client configs and the appropriate routes was all that was needed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
